# Table on page is giving back errors, but works fine

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, datatables

Every time I reload the page I receive a pop-up window with error:

> DataTables warning: table id=data-table - Requested unknown parameter
>   'apply_to_workdays' for row 0, column 5. For more information about
>   this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4

Assuming from the link data table is trying to get some value but it is unable to get it. The table shows up fine. I get no other errors, just those two on reload.

it shows error about `apply_to_workdays` but the column with it shows up perfectly, and everything works fine. I get no other errors in console/network tab.

my blade.php

```php
<div class="table-responsive dt-responsive">
        <table id="data-table" style="width: 100%;" class="display">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="text-center">Unit</th>
                <th></th>
                <th>Competence Level</th>
                <th style="padding-left: 0" class>Quantity</th>
                <th style="padding-right: 0" class="text-right">Start -</th>
                <th style="padding-left: 0" class="text-left">Finish</th>
                <th style="width: 1px">Workdays</th>
                <th style="width: 1px">Weekends</th>
                <th style="width: 1px">Holidays</th>
                <th class="text-center">Practice Type</th>
                <th style="width: 10%">Action</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </div>
```

JS for it:

```
(function () {
    const url = 'rotation-needs';
    const positionUrl = url + '/position';
    const buttonColumn = 9;
    const definitionFieldValues = ['name', 'description', 'active', 'apply_to_workdays', 'apply_to_weekends', 'apply_to_holidays'];
    const definition_id = 'schedule_need_definition_id';
    const required = [true, false, true];
    const columnDefs = [
            {targets: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], orderable: false},
            {orderable: false, className: 'reorder', targets: [buttonColumn]},
            {
                targets: buttonColumn,
                render: function (data, type, row) {
                    return "<button type=\"edit-button\"  data-toggle=\"modal\" data-target=\"#edit-position-Modal\"class=\"tabledit-edit-button btn btn-primary waves-effect waves-light\" style=\"float: none;  margin-right: 1vw;\"><span class=\"icofont icofont-ui-edit\"></span></button>"
                        + "<button type=\"button\" id=\" \" data-toggle=\"modal\" data-target=\"#remove-Modal\"class=\"tabledit-delete-button btn btn-danger waves-effect waves-light active\" style=\"float: none;\"><span class=\"icofont icofont-ui-delete\"></span></button>";
                }
            },
            {
                targets: 0,
                "createdCell": function (td, data, rowData, row, col) {
                    $(td).css('background-color', data.color);
                    $(td).css('color', colors.getContrasting(data.color));
                },
                render: function (data, type, row) {
                    if (type === 'display') {
                        return '';
                    } else {
                        return data;
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                targets: [1], className: 'text-center',
                render: function (data, type, row) {
                    var result = '';
                    if (row.competence_level_id_min.name !== null) {
                        result = result + 'min. ' + row.competence_level_id_min.name + ' <br>';
                    }
                    if (row.competence_level_id_max.name !== null) {
                        result = result + 'max. ' + row.competence_level_id_max.name;
                    }
                    return result;
                },
                "createdCell": function (td, data, rowData, row, col) {
                    $(td).css('background-color', rowData.organization_unit.color);
                    $(td).css('border-top', '1px solid #ddd');
                    $(td).css('color', colors.getContrasting(rowData.organization_unit.color));
                }
            },
            {
                targets: 2, className: 'text-center'
            },
            {
                targets: 3, className: 'text-right',
                render: function (data, type, row) {
                    return data.substring(0, 5);
                }
            },
            {
                targets: 4, className: 'text-left',
                render: function (data, type, row) {
                    return data.substring(0, 5);
                }
            },
            {
                targets: 5, className: 'text-center',
                render: function (data) {
                    if (data !== 0) {
                        return "<label class=\"badge badge-success\">✔</label>";
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                targets: 6, className: 'text-center',
                render: function (data) {
                    if (data !== 0) {
                        return "<label class=\"badge badge-success\">✔</label>";
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                targets: 7, className: 'text-center',
                render: function (data) {
                    if (data !== 0) {
                        return "<label class=\"badge badge-success\">✔</label>";
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                targets: 8, className: 'text-center',
                render: function (data, type, row) {
                    var result = '';
                    if (row.practice_type_id === 1) {
                        /*result = result + row.practice_type_id.name + ' <br>'; - na szybko bo nie wiem czmeu nie pobiera name*/
                        result = 'On-call';
                    } else if (row.practice_type_id === 2) {
                        result = 'Rotation';
                    } else {
                        result = 'Not assigned';
                    }
                    return result;
                }
            },
        ]
    ;
    const columns = [
        {"data": "organization_unit"},
        {"data": "competence_level_id_min"},
        {"data": "quantity"},
        {"data": 'time_start'},
        {'data': 'time_finish'},
        {'data': 'apply_to_workdays'},
        {'data': 'apply_to_weekends'},
        {'data': 'apply_to_holidays'},
        {'data': 'practice_type_id'},
        {'data': 'schedule_need_definition_position_id'}
    ];

        create.setOnHashSuccess(hash.switchToNew);
        create.createHashItemButton(definitionFieldValues, url, required);

        update.updateHashMenuItem(definitionFieldValues, url + '/get');
        update.confirmUpdateHashMenuItem(url + "/update", definition_id, definitionFieldValues, required);

        remove.removeHashMenuItem();
        remove.confirmRemoveHashMenuItem(url, hash.onRemove);

        dataTable.rowGrouping(0);
        dataTable.displayLength(100);


        need.initializeSelects();
        need.initializeCreate();
        need.initializeTableCRUD(url + '/position');
        need.generate();

        update.setOnSuccess(function () {
            sidebar.loadContent(undefined, function () {
                sidebar.setActive(hash.getCurrent());
            });
        });

        errorHandling.alertDismissButton();
    });
}());
```

Comment: Would you please check the output of you browser console and let us know if there are any errors and what they are saying?

Comment: The problem is that I dont get any errors over there :/ @frankfurt-laravel only the pop-up window

Comment: OK, did you check https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/4 ?

Comment: Yeah, I was checking that my guess is that I have more columns in HTML than in the JS, but even if I delete one it doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: You have 11 columns as per HTML

Comment: I know, but it should still work, even if I delete one column in HTML it gives me that error. Anyway it should still work using the link provided (datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/4) `Using columns or columnDefs you have specified more columns than there are in the HTML`

Answer (score 0):

Solved my issue, in my columnDefs (target 5,6,7) I had if statements without else statements I changed from:

```
 {
                targets: 5, className: 'text-center',
                render: function (data) {
                    if (data !== 0) {
                        return "<label class=\"badge badge-success\">✔</label>";
                    }
                }
         },
```

to:

```
{
                targets: 5, className: 'text-center',
                render: function (data) {
                    if (data !== 0) {
                        return "<label class=\"badge badge-success\">✔</label>";
                    } else {
                        return "<label class=\"badge badge-danger\">X</label>";
                    }
                }
            },
```